# pass return of a function into another

Tags: python, class

I have a question / problem and I don't know how to solve it. Suppose you have three functions, function 1, function 2 and function 3. In function 1 you do some operations and you give a specific return which will be used as input for the second function. In the second function you do some specific calculation and also finish with return, which you pass in a third function

My problem is that as soon as I pass the return of function 1 into function 2 all the calculation in function 1 is repeated (calculation is here in this case, several plots) The same goes for function two into three, now I get results from function 1 and function 2. I hope you do understand what I mean.

What I want is just the return value of func 1 for func 2 and return value of func 2 for three and not the entire function body.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
class test:
    def __(self)__:
        self.attribute1=pd.read_csv(...)
        self.attribite2=pd.read_csv(...)

    def func1(self):
        plt.plot(a,b)
        plt.plot(c,d)
        return x

    def func2(self):
        self.data_2=self.func1()
        plt.plot(e,f)
        plt.plot(g,h)
        return y

    def func3(self):
        self.data_3=self.func2()
        plt.plot(i,j)

data_test=test()
print(data_test.func2())
```

My problem is that (let's focus on func2). If I use the input from func1 and execute my code for func2 I get also the two plots. I dont want to have that. I just want to see the plots(e,f) and plots(g,h) instead of plots(a,b), plots(c,d), plots(e,f) and plots(g,h)

Comment: Please mind correct indentation when sharing your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class definition do not follow the OOP clean design, for which every method should performa the most atomic task possible.

Your methods `func1`, `func2` and `func3`, they all do at least 2 tasks: plot something and return something else.

Consider changing your class so every method do one and only one thing, defining public APIS and private methods, for instance:

```
class test:
    def __(self)__:
        self.attribute1 = []
        self.attribite2 = []

    def _func1(self):
        return x

    def _func2(self):
        self.data_2 = self._func1()
        return y

    def _func3(self):
        self.data_3 = self._func2()

    def func2(self):
        self._func2()
        plt.plot(e,f)
        plt.plot(g,h)

    def func3(self):
        self._func3()
        plt.plot(e,f)
        plt.plot(g,h)

data_test=test()
data_test.func2()
```

This way `func2` and `func3` are public apis (aka: intended to be called from outside the class) that will "do the work" (setting stuff in `self.data_2` and `self.data_3`) AND plot; while `_func2` and `_func3` are private methods (aka, methods that only the class itself is supposed to use) will only do the work.
Now, calling `func2` will use methods `_func1` and `_func2`, but only plot what's defined in `func2`.

Comment: Just to be sure. So what you mean is to put the maximum amount of "similarities" between the function into the __init__(self) and then use the specific information for each function from __init__(self). So consider __init(self) with its whole expression as a "distributor", where each function (func1, func2) should call the information required from it?

Answer (score 1):

You say that you "pass the return of function 1 into function 2", but you never do that.

You're not passing any results anywhere, and none of your functions take any input (except `self`) - you're calling the functions directly in each one.
In other words, every time you call `function2`, it calls `function1`, and every time you call `function3`, it calls `function2`, which in turn calls `function1`.

Code that matches your description would look like this:

```
class test:
    def __(self)__:
        self.attribute1=pd.read_csv(...)
        self.attribite2=pd.read_csv(...)

    def func1(self):
        plt.plot(a,b)
        plt.plot(c,d)
        return x

    def func2(self, a):
        self.data_2 = a
        plt.plot(e,f)
        plt.plot(g,h)
        return y

    def func3(self, x):
        self.data_3 = x
        plt.plot(i,j)
        return z

data_test = test()
print(data_test.func3(data_test.func2(data_test.func1())))
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but the way I understood (and this might be wrong which is why I am asking) is that the return of the functio, let's say return of func1 (x) is implemented in func2.
Another question: What is in your self.data_2 the "a"?

Comment: `a` is the parameter that is the input to `func2`. Its value will be the return value from `data_test.func1()` (see the use below it). I think you need to read some more about function parameters and return values in your favourite book.